# Sort links to other SE sites at the bottom of each SE site by relevance

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, stackexchange-2.0

For example for [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com), the most relevant other SE sites are probably [Maths](http://math.stackexchange.com), [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). It would be nice to have the links arranged by relevance, possibly emphasizing the first three or five by a large font size.

Comment: What about when there aren't really any sites of "relevance"? What would Seasoned Advice get? Or Home Improvement?

Comment: @GraceNote: I'd guess Seasoned Advice could relate to [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)... But yes, you're right, in case there are no obvious "relevant" other SE sites, the ordering should remain unchanged. (Maybe someone can figure out numbers and a measure how close each site is connected to all others to determine this...)

Comment: I'd suggest that Seasoned Advice is more likely than you think to relate to other artistic endeavors.  Also what about Homebrew, when it graduates?  I think related sites will pop up.

Comment: @Tobias the sites that have migration paths are obviously linked together. However, I think it would be better to mimic the same clustering from Area51 on Stack Exchange

Comment: The footer will need some reorganizing indeed. While valuable for google juice, I distinctly remember Gaming having 5 lines worth of footer links to sister betas at one point... That's some serious footage.

Comment: @Tobias - How would Seasoned Advice (A cooking site) relate to Electronics Development (An electrical engineering site?)  ELECTRONICS IS NOT ABOUT CONSUMER DEVICES!!!!  Bah.   Though I agree that I'd like to see this feature.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: admittedly, it _is_ far fetched unless you try to design your own oven... sorry for the bad example